# kubernetes clustering architecture for zero down time

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, replication

As I found, the best way to have  zero down time even when one datacenter is down, is using kubernetes between at least two servers from two datacenters.

So because I wanted  to use servers in Iran. I've heard low performance about infrastructure.

The question is that if I want to have master-master replication for mysql, in one server failure, how can I sync repaired server in kubernetes clustring?

Answer (score 1):

K8s is the platform, it doesn't change how MySQL HA works. Example, if you have dedicated servers for MySQL, these servers become "pods" in K8s. What you need to do **at MySQL level** when any of the server is gone for whatever reason; is the same as what you need to do when you run it as a pod. In fact, K8s help you by automatically start a new pod. Where in former case, you will need to provision a new physical server - the time required is obvious here. You will normally run script to re-establish the HA, the same apply to K8s where you can run the recovery script as the init container before the actual MySQL server container is started.